# How to delete a directory based on date and time

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

The below script will be called from a cronjob and my desire is to remove directories older than 10 mins of the current time.

I'm having trouble with the following in my script:

- Trimming `\n` from the beginning of a variable and not from the end (dumping the `$oldDirday` variable below to hexdump shows a leading `\n`
- Adding 600 seconds to the current time
- Getting `if` test to work properly

This is what I have:

```
#!/bin/sh

i=1
homeDirData="/home/user"$i"/dirToClean/"

while [ -d $homeDirData ]
do
   echo "Checking user"$i""

   for oldDir in $(find . -type d)
   do
      oldDirDay=$(ls -l $oldDir | awk '{print $7}')
      oldDirTime=$(ls -l $oldDir | awk '{print $8}' | tr -d ':')

      curDay=$(date +%d%t%R | awk '{print $1}')
      curTime=$(date +%d%t%R | awk '{print $2}')

      if [ $oldDirDay -lt $curDay ] && [ $oldDirTime -lt $(($curTime+600)) ]
      then
         find $homeDirData -type f -exec shred -f --remove {} \;
         rm -rf $homeDirData
      else
         echo "Nothing to remove"
      fi

      ((i+1))
   done
done
```

**Error**

- line 17: [: too many arguments (where the `if` statement is)

**Issue**

- Nothing is being deleted

Comment: You need to quote variables inside `[ ]` block. Also, you don't need `$` sigil inside `(( ))` block.

Comment: Also, instead of `curDay=$(date +%d%t%R | awk '{print $1}')`, why don't you `curDay=$(date +%d)`? The same for `$curTime`.

Comment: @fedorqui heh... that is much easier :-P

Comment: Don't parse `ls`.  Use `find` with `-mmin` option.

Comment: @devnull assuming you mean `-amin`, this option doesn't work with against directories.  Well I haven't gotten it to work...

Comment: @devnull disregard, there is an `-mmin` and that does seem to work!   That simplified my code quite a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
find $homeDirData -type d -mmin +10 -print0 | xargs -0 rmdir
```